# How to access the "Grandchild" of 2 has_many associations in rails without adding another association?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm having trouble figuring out how to access the "grandchild" of an object in rails. Here's my example:

I have a product model that can have options (such as "size" or "color") and each option can have choices (such as "small, medium, large" or "red, green, blue").

```
class Product < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :options
end

class Option < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :product
  has_many :choices
end

class Choice < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :option
end
```

I'd like to access the "choices" from the Product controller, but I can't figure out how to chain them together.

For instance, `Product.first.options` returns all of the associated options that belong to the Product, but I'd like to do something like `Product.first.options.choices`.

That returns `NoMethodError (undefined method 'choices')`

Is this even possible with active record or do I need to create another association that connects Product and Choice.

Comment: You can add `has_many :choices, through: :options` to `Product` and then `Product.first.choices` will work

Comment: Thanks engineersmnky. I figured that was true, I was wondering if there was a way to do that without adding anything else to the model like that.

Answer (score 0):

@engineersmnky came through with the comment that solved this.

Here's what I added to get this working.

`has_many :choices, through: :options` was added to the `Product` model:

```
class Product < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :options
  has_many :choices,  through: :options
end
```

And then here was the simple_form code that gave me the user experience I was looking for in the `product#edit` view:

```
<% @product.options.each do |option| %>
    <div class='form-row'>
      <div class='col'>
        <%= f.association :choices,
                          collection: option.choices,
                          as: :radio_buttons,
                          label: option.name  %>
      </div><!-- /.col -->
    </div><!-- /.row -->
  <% end %>
```